# How to match JSP pages under WEB-INF in a servlet filter

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Is there a way to tell my filter to match only the JSP pages I put under `/WEB-INF`?

Comment: [Take a step back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem exactly are you trying to solve with such a filter?

Comment: I check if a user is logged in or not. So i need i a filter to make this control, every time a page is called.

Comment: Why don't you just match specific URLs instead of specific JSPs? Or is the URL structure of your webapp a mess? You'd better solve that first so that you can just match specific URLs instead of JSPs, exactly as where a filter is initially designed for. Hover with your mouse the `[servlet-filters]` tag below the question until a black info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: My webapp structure is a mess, i have to "fix" it, you are right